# windows server 2019 remote desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2019

Hi Win Server OS experts,

I'm trying to set up our Win Server 2019 system for a Remote Desktop Licensing server. We purchased the Remote Desktop per Device CALs and we are trying to make the CALs work. The RD licensing manager looks like it's running, but we couldn't set up the Remote Desktop Service Role so that the licenses can be issued. Please see the screenshots below.

(We are using a single device to host the server 2019, and to issue RD licenses. I think it's a Workgroup environment after some research. I created user accounts for ppl to log in the RD sessions)

The problem now is that I couldn't find the **Remote Desktop Host Role** in the role list. Currently two users can log in simultaneously. The Licensing server is not issuing any licenses, nonetheless the licensing manager is running and status shows "OK".

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrmb5.png)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWDxm.png)

[Screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpSnC.png)

[Screenshot4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgjnZ.png)

**Update July 7**: I started a thread on MS Forums: here is the link, I included more screenshots there: [MS Forum link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/65d5314e-7d7f-482a-b22e-a4371d1d9e3a/can-not-issue-licenses-from-server-2019?forum=winserverTS)

Comment: That error is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That did not help. I searched for the error but I couldn't find the solutions that's why I posted. I could not activate the RD Host role, it didn't exist in the role list. I'll add more information in the question, but please remove the -1. If it's **that** obvious, could you help?

Comment: "The local server must be joined to the domain" -- did you actually join it to a domain?

Comment: No. I didn't add it to a domain. There is one local machine to run the OS and RD licensing. We do not have a domain.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I did some search (I'm a Linux guy not a Win guy but I got this assignment anyways, shrug), and realized that we are in the "workgroup environment" rather than the "domain environment". That is, we have multiple devices accessing the server machine using RD connections, while each of the people accessing it has a user account on the server 2019. In this case, what can I do? Our company can pay consultants to solve the problem. Price negotiable. Contact me.

Answer (score 3):

To deploy in Workgroup's mode, you need to select **Role Based and/or feature-based**, and then select **Remote Desktop Session Host & Remote Desktop Licensing**

You can't use the ***Remote Desktop Services Installation***'s method if you are in a workgroup.

Please make sure you have configured your primary DNS's suffix correctly too, that would make sure you have a correct FQDN.

A side note; Your CAL must be RDS Device CAL, and for that you seem ok, you can't use RDS User CAL in workgroup's mode.

Comment: Thanks. @yagmoth555. The problem is that when I tried what you said, **Role Based and/or feature-based**, only the **Remote Desktop Licensing** shows up, but not the **Host**. I don't know what else I need to activate the Host role. Could you re-evaluate the situation? I've added a screenshot to the revised question. Thanks again!

Comment: @frankliuao What version you have of 2019 ? The RDSH role re-emerged in the Windows Server 2019 LTSC Preview Build 17650, it was removed due to a bug in some early release. So let me know what media you used to install

Comment: I purchased recently from MS and I installed the newest updates. It was installed from an ISO image file downloaded from the official website.

Comment: I wrote a question on MS forum, you probably will see the question more clearly there: [forum link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/65d5314e-7d7f-482a-b22e-a4371d1d9e3a/can-not-issue-licenses-from-server-2019?forum=winserverTS)